# Google AdMob not showing ads in real time in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

I developing a Flutter and added Google adMob to my app. While intializing admob I used appId and used adID also in required places But the realtime ad was not shown. In debug console it says something like ad not loaded error 3. On searching internet some suggested to install the apk of a release version. I also tried it and nothing works.

My code just works fine for testAds but not for the real-time ads.

When I change testDeviceAd to my adId it doesn't show anything.

My account has be also approved by admob. What's the reason for this?

Comment: Hi, have you find a solution for this? I'm facing same. Can you please kindly help me?

Comment: @Kavindhi yep, I found this. The thing is that google will analyze your apps traffic and number of requests made based on that if google thinks that it can make some profit then they will provide you some real ads.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! will look into it